# Массив из имён с заглавной буквы

Tags: javascript, массивы

Я попробовал написать так:

```
let names = ['KosTya', 'serGey', 'JoRDan', 'aleksandr'];
for (let name of names) {
    name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1);
    console.log(name);
}
```

Это хоть и делает заглавной первую букву, однако потом буквы того же регистра, какого они были изначально. Мне же нужно, чтоб первая буква была заглавной, а остальные - нет.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let names = ['KosTya', 'serGey', 'JoRDan', 'aleksandr'];

let new_names = names.map(n => n[0].toUpperCase() + n.slice(1).toLowerCase())

console.log(new_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли перевести все буквы в нижний регистр до того, как перевели первую в верхний.

Иначе говоря, таков алгоритм:

- есть слово, например: `пАШа`
- все буквы переводятся в нижний регистр, получаем `паша`
- Затем первая буква переводится в верхний регистр, остальные остаются как есть: `Паша`

Надо также заметить, что в использовании `charAt()` [уже нет особого смысла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943760), и можно получить букву тем же способом, что в массиве (bracket notation)

```js
let names = ['KosTya', 'serGey', 'JoRDan', 'aleksandr'];

for (let name of names) {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    name = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substr(1);
    console.log(name);
}
```